# how to perform log10 transform on specific columns by a condition in R

Tags: r, database, conditional-statements

May dataset is like this:

```
d <- read.table('age.txt', header = F,sep=' ')

 V1   V2  V3       V4   V5    V6        V7       V8       V9         V10
1 101 12  3.531704 16.0 40.8  1.449648  1.080353 20.85738 74.53056   0
2 102 15 -9.000000 24.0 36.4 -9.000000 -9.000000 -9.00000 -9.00000   0
3 103 13  3.306023 26.2 48.4  2.178820  1.349228 22.51904 72.82571   2.3
4 104 12  2.715226 18.2 42.6  2.343138  1.414314 23.13632 72.73414   4.5
```

and I need to perform log10 transform on column 6:10, but only for the values that are not equal to 0 or -9. Well, I tried this:

```
if(d[,6:10]!=-9 || 0){d[,6:10]=log10(d[,6:10])}
```

but it did not work. If anyone can help thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to loop through the columns 6:10, get the index of elements that are not 0 or -9, apply the `log10` on those and return the `vector`.

```
d[6:10] <-  lapply(d[6:10], function(x)  {
                 i1 <- !x %in% c(0, -9)
                 x[i1] <- log10(x[i1])
                 x} )
```

---

Or another option would be to create a logical matrix ('i1') subset the elements from the columns and update with the `log10`

```
i1 <- d[6:10]!=0 & d[6:10] != -9
d[6:10][i1] <- log10(d[6:10][i1])
```

Answer (score 3):

log2 or log10?

```
m <- as.matrix(df[6:10])
df[6:10] <- ifelse(m > 0, log10(m), m)
```